# How to use django-ckeditor to specify different image upload paths for different models?

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

The usual practice is to define `CKEDITOR_UPLOAD_PATH = 'uploads/'` in `settings.py`. But this will save the images in all models in a unique path. Is it possible to assign a different image path to each model?

```py
class BlogModel(models.Model):
    ......
    content = RichTextUploadingField() # image upload to /media/blog/

class NewsModel(models.Model):
    ......
    content = RichTextUploadingField() # image upload to /media/news/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a path by using FileField `upload_to='pathname'`

```
class BlogModel(models.Model)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='blog/')


class NewsModel(models.Model)
    content = models.FileField(upload_to='news/')
```

Blogmodel content will be uploaded to `/media/blog/`

Newsmodel content will be uploaded to `/media/news/`

You can also do:

```
content = models.FileField(upload_to='pathname/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Will be saved as  `/pathname/2019/04/04/`

Comment: This is not what I want, It does not provide editing capabilities. Thank you for your answer anyway.